# Delete all tags except allowed, keeping the text content in HTML

Tags: html, typescript, dom

An html element is input, and its contents must be converted to the desired format. All unresolved tags must be removed, but the text must remain. The contents of the input element can be nested in any way. The list of allowed tags can change. Without using RegEx.

My approach to the solution. Create a list of allowed tags. Recursively go through all `childNodes`, reaching elements without children. Check each `Node` against the list. If there is - do nothing, if not - delete, leaving the contents.

That's what I'm stuck on. Perhaps a different approach is needed. If that's the case, I'd be happy to figure it out. I write in Typescript.

```
const formating = (currElem: HTMLElement, whiteList: Array<string>) => {
    currElem.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
        console.log(child)
        if (child.hasChildNodes())
            formating(child as HTMLElement, whiteList);
        if (!(child.nodeName in whiteList)) {              
            
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `element.tagName` and `element.replaceWith`

```
// select every tag
let allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*')

// allowed list of tags as a set for perf. UPPERCASE as in tagName
const allowedTags = new Set(['A', 'B', 'DIV'])

// to start from the end, from deeper tags
let allElementsReversed = allElements.reverse()

for (let tag of allElementsReversed) {
  if (!allowedTags.has(tag.tagName)) {
    // replace bad tag with its children
    tag.replaceWith(...tag.childNodes)
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an error at the `let allElementsReversed = allElements.reverse()` line: `The "reverse" property does not exist in the "NodeListOf<Element>" type`. What do I need to change?

Comment: It seems to work as it should: `let allElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'));`